# Microsoft Chatbot -"There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Forbidden" after deploying on Azure

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

I am building a chatbot on `Bot Framework 4` on `.NetCore2.2`. The chatbot has LUIS, QnA Maker integrated in it and it works perfectly fine locally in Emulator with and without security (Microsoft APP ID/ Password). After I deploy it on Azure using `Azure DevOps` it gives me the error below: [image]

I have followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). It works fine locally but not after deployment on Azure.

Here is my appsetting.json.

```
{
 "Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Warning"
}
},

"botFilePath": "nlp-with-dispatch.bot",
"botFileSecret": "",
"MicrosoftAppId": "a8402bb0-3a7a-4727-a2b1-e8012b009732",
"MicrosoftAppPassword": "<password here>",

"QnAKnowledgebaseId": "55c79164-f0f1-4b4e-ab7e-1a5481227683",
"QnAEndpointKey": "<key here>",
"QnAEndpointHostName": 
"https://<name>.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker",

"LuisAppId": "44d2cf32-153d-4d57-b5ac-30e34be7faa3",
"LuisAPIKey": "<key here>",
"LuisAPIHostName": "westus",
"AllowedHosts": "*"
 }
```

**EDIT 1:** I am getting the following in browser console when I try to test from Test in Web Chat.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
When I add Microsoft APP ID and Password in Emulator when working on localhost, my bot gets Authentication error in Emulator.

**EDIT 3:** This is the exception I am getting

> POST to CivicTheBot failed: POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 403 System.Exception at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI.ThrowOnFailedStatusCode

**EDIT 4:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFramework;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using IntermediatorBotSample.Middleware;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Core.Extensions;
using System;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TraceExtensions;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
public class Startup
    {

    public IConfiguration Configuration
        {
        get;
        }
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
       var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, 
    reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", 
    optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        { 


   services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion
   (CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // Create the Bot Framework Adapter with error handling enabled.
        services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, 
    AdapterWithErrorHandler>();

        // Create the bot services (LUIS, QnA) as a singleton.
        services.AddSingleton<IBotServices, BotServices>();

        // Create the bot as a transient.
        services.AddTransient<IBot, DispatchBot>();

        // Create the User state.
        services.AddSingleton<UserState>();

        services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
        services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration);

        services.AddBot<DispatchBot>(options =>
        {
         //   options.CredentialProvider = new 
     ConfigurationCredentialProvider(Configuration);
     options.Middleware.Add(new CatchExceptionMiddleware<Exception>(async 
     (context, exception) =>
            {
    await context.TraceActivityAsync("Bot Exception", 
    exception);
    await context.SendActivityAsync($"Sorry, it looks like 
    something went wrong: {exception.Message}");
            }));
    // Handoff middleware
            options.Middleware.Add(new HandoffMiddleware(Configuration));
        });

        services.AddMvc(); // Required Razor pages
        }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to 
    configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment 
    env)
        {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
        else
            {
            app.UseHsts();
            }

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseBotFramework();
        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Can u clean the app service and redeploy or try with new app service instance.

Comment: i can create a new bot and deploy there. Let me try that. But can you elaborate why this error occurs?

Comment: Have you entered your credentials correctly on the Settings page?Also, check if the messaging endpoint is configured correctly. You can also check for the detailed error message in the dev console(F12).

Comment: I have double checked the credentials on configuration page in azure and my appsetting.json file.

Comment: Can you check what error are you getting on the dev console when you test in web chat? Also, is your messaging endpoint in the format https://<botName>.azurewebsites.net/api/messages?

Comment: I got this error on dev console: `webchat-es5.js:30 POST https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/6asMHasetbCHHxwpxLleuK-g/activities 502`

Comment: The error indicates that either the request timed out or the bot returned an error.  Can you try to create new web app bot with a new App Service plan, and then upgrade the Bot Builder SDK for your bot application and publish it to that corresponding app service to check if your bot application can work with the new bot service?

Comment: @ranusharao the SDK is updated. I will work on setting up a new app service plan as you recommended and get back to you...mind you it might take a day or so.

Comment: still the same error. I am using deployment center with azure repo to deploy my bot.

Comment: Can you post the steps on how you are deploying your bot?

Comment: @ranusharao I have tried 3 different approaches. I have tried connecting my github and deploying from deployment center in my Bot app. I used the publish profile method and the one here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=erg%2Ccsharp

Comment: @ranusharao i made some edits in my question. Please look and see if it helps you

Comment: @hkhan, can you post your startup.cs code? Also, are you sure the MicrosoftAppId in the appsettings.json is the one associated with your botHandle CivicTheBot? I looked up the logs on our end, but it shows a different AppID for the botHandle CivicTheBot.

Comment: @ranushrao I am sure it is the same. I will still double check. I will post my code shortly.

Comment: @ranusharao I have added my startup.cs code in the question. I also compared my MicrosoftAppID and AppPassword in my appsetting.json and bot webapp in Azure. They are the same.

Comment: @ranusharao I checked my app registration and matched the MicrosoftAppID and MicrosoftPassword I get the following error now `POST to CivicTheBot failed: POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 403`

Comment: @hkhan, is your messaging endpoint in the format https://<botName>.azurewebsites.net/api/messages?

Comment: @ranusharao it is.

Comment: @hkhan, the 403 error denotes a disconnect with the AppId/password. Can you confirm that your AppID starts with 979******* or a840********?

Comment: @ranusharao I deleted those bots from my azure environment and also the app registration....I created a new bot and the new app ID starts with ac96*********

Comment: Can you post your botHandle? I will look up the logs on our end. Checking for 'CivicTheBot' shows there is no bot with this id.

Comment: @ranusharao CivicDevBot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197890/discussion-between-ranusharao-and-hkhan).